Set admin theme by user
Is it possible to set a different admin theme by user ?
I found this old module https://www.drupal.org/project/tbr
it's probably possible to convert it to fit the new Drupal 8/10 system (https://www.drupal.org/node/2158619)
Does a solution already exist ?

You can use module theme_switcher

You can use either of the below modules

Theme Switcher Rules (https://www.drupal.org/project/theme_switcher) --> Has more control and options, OR
Theme Switcher By User (https://www.drupal.org/project/tsbu) --> Better suited for your use case

